# How can I provide a Jacl package from the classpath?

Tags: java, tcl, jacl

I need to distribute some TCL code as part of an enterprise application, and this code must be available to all nodes in the cluster.  Due to security policy, the Tcl interpreter cannot access the TCL code from the filesystem, so I must make it available in a jar in the EAR itself.

How can I convince Jacl (1.4.1, if it matters) to find a pkgIndex.tcl for a package on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacl is looking for pkgIndex in the variable auto_path

if you execute the command puts $auto_path you see the entires for example:

resource:/tcl/lang/library

add your path with : lappend auto_path resource:

Comment: Interestingly enough, you're half right.  However, Jacl had a bug in its pkgUnknown procedure that prevented that from working.  I've had to patch it locally in order to use that feature.